# Is it possible to have low test error and high training error for a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, variance

When we have large test error and large training error then we say it a BIAS problem. When we have low training error and high test error then we say it VARIANCE problem. When both training error and test error are enough low for being acceptable  we say it GOOD fit or BEST fit model.

But is it possible to have more training error then test error???
If yes then what do we say it??
Also test and training sets are randomly selected so no prior setting is done!

```
Training    Test    Model
error       error

low         low     GOOD FIT
low         high    HIGH VARIANCE
high        high    HIGH BIAS
high        low     ????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As learning models aim to reduce the training error (since the test set is not available while learning, hence the "test") this is very improbable, and i'd say unless you specifically create some example where this happens, it won't happen.

For it to happen the training set would have to be one of a high variance, or one incompatible with the chosen model (e.g. a linear model separating data that cannot be separated linearly) would create a high training error, for any test set to produce a low training error it would have to not reflect the same variance as in the training set given. If you encounter such a problem, it's probably bad construction of these sets. As this scenario is so unlikely i'm not aware of any name given to it